# Springboot @Valid annotation with String object

Tags: spring, validation, methods, parameters

So, I have the following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{application}/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public MyObject getUsers(@RequestParam("itemId") String itemId, @PathVariable("application") String application) {
    return userService.get(itemId, application);
}
```

I would like to check if the request parameter **itemId** exists in the related **application** (in the path).

My first idea was to create a validator :

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{application}/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@CheckItemId
public MyObject getUsers(@RequestParam("itemId") String itemId, @PathVariable("application") String application) {
    return userService.get(itemId, application);
}
```

CheckItemId.java :

```
@Target({METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckItemIdValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface CheckItemId {
    String message() default "error";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

CheckItemIdValidator.java :

```
@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)
public class CheckItemIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckItemId, Object[]>{


    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object[] arg0, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {
        String itemId= (String) arg0[0];
        String application = (String) arg0[1];

        // Logic business ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

This implementation works well, I managed to get the values **itemId** and **application** in the validator. I can now do my verification.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do something like that? Since I handle an array of Object, I need to cast it to String and If I change the parameters order, I will not get the same values since I need to use arg0[0] and arg0[1].

Thank you !

Comment: It depends upon the business logic. If you are doing simple checks like (min or max value check, max or min check, null check) then you can use hibernator validator API. If the business logic is complex, then this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring validation library. Add `@Valid` on controller level. Then add `@NotBlank` on method level as below.

```
getUsers(@RequestParam("itemId") @NotBlank String itemId)
```